# Compiler complains unless one dictionary enum key is explicitly referenced

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, types

I have the following enum:

```
enum TaskKey: String{
    case title = "title"
    case completed = "completed"
    case children = "children"
}
```

Now using these keys I create a dictionary:

```
    let taskDescriptions : Array<[TaskKey:Any]> = [
        [ .title : "Buy milk",
          .completed : false ],

        [ .title     : "Sleep",
          .completed : false,
          .children  :
            [
                // `TaskKey` is required here
                [ TaskKey.title     : "Find a bed",
                  .completed : false
                ],

                [ .title     : "Wait",
                  .completed : false
                ]
            ] ],

        [ .title     : "Dance",
          .completed : false ]
        ]
```

Now since my dictionary is typed `<[TaskKey:Any]>` I may use the `.title` instead of `TaskKey.title`. However, for the `.children` where the whole dictionary is nested I need at least one `TaskKey.` reference or the compiler will complain.

To me this seems a bit weird. I would assume that the compiler implicitly types the children from `Any` to so `TaskKey:Any` as soon as I add one key like I do in my example.

I wonder if my assumption is correct. Also for cosmetics sake is it possible to use the `.title` syntax also for nested entries in my dictionary.

Comment: Unrelated but the explicit string values in the enum are redundant. This does exactly the same:  `enum TaskKey : String { case title, completed, children }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nested children are completely independent.  The outer dictionary is `[TaskKey:Any]` so the inner array can be of any type.  The compiler needs some information about what a `.title` is.  As soon as you make one of the keys explicit with `TaskKey.title`, Swift infers the rest.

The other way to do it is to use explicit casting (`as [[TaskKey:Any]]` or equivalently `as Array<[TaskKey:Any]>`) to tell Swift the inner type:

```
let taskDescriptions : Array<[TaskKey:Any]> = [
    [ .title : "Buy milk",
      .completed : false ],

    [ .title     : "Sleep",
      .completed : false,
      .children  :
        [
            // `TaskKey` is required here
            [ .title     : "Find a bed",
              .completed : false
            ],

            [ .title     : "Wait",
              .completed : false
            ]
        ] as [[TaskKey:Any]] ],

    [ .title     : "Dance",
      .completed : false ]
]
```

**Note:** Making things easy for the Swift compiler by explicitly specifying the types will improve compile times.

---

**Consider using a `struct` or `class`:**

I'm not sure a dictionary is the best choice of data structure here.  You might want to consider using a `struct` or `class`:

```
class Task: CustomStringConvertible {
    var title: String
    var completed: Bool
    var children: [Task]
    var description: String { return "Task(title: \(title), completed: \(completed), children: \(children)" }  

    init(title: String, completed: Bool, children: [Task] = []) {
        self.title = title
        self.completed = completed
        self.children = children
    }
}

var taskDescriptions : [Task] = [
    Task(title: "Buy milk",
         completed: false
    ),

    Task(title: "Sleep",
      completed: false,
      children:
        [
            Task(title: "Find a bed",
              completed: false
            ),

            Task(title: "Wait",
              completed: false
            )
        ]
    ),

    Task(title: "Dance",
      completed: false
    )
]
```

That is going to be much easier to access than having to deal with casting `Any` to the desired type.

The advantage of using a `class` here (over a `struct`) is that it enables you to easily update the inner tasks:

For example:

```
// Mark all of the children tasks of the second task as completed
for task in taskDescriptions[1].children {
    task.completed = true
}
```

Comment: +1 also for the note at the end; not only do explicit types often make it easier for humans, it makes compiling easier (faster) for the compiler, too.